# When I try to login a user, I get a weird error with 200 status code

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, laravel-9

I'm developing Laravel 9 and Vue.js 3 app (a simple social network) at the moment. I have a problem described in the title. The error itself:
[image]

Here are the pieces of code that might help you. [And this is the link to the repository of my project on GitHub.](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst)

[`Login.vue`, if you will need it](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst/blob/main/resources/js/views/auth/Login.vue) (the code is too long to paste here).

`loginUser()` action:

```js
loginUser(ctx, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ctx.commit('setInProcess', true, { root: true });
            axios.post('api/login', payload).then(response => {
                if (response.data.access_token) {
                    ctx.commit('setLoggedIn', true, { root: true })
                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access_token);
                    ctx.commit('setToken', response.data.access_token, { root: true })
                    resolve(response);
                    router.push('/');
                } else {
                    ctx.dispatch(
                        'setAndDisplayErrors',
                        [ctx.rootState.helper.undefinedErrorMessage],
                        { root: true }
                    );
                    reject(response)
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                if (error.response.data.errors) {
                    ctx.dispatch(
                        'setAndDisplayErrors',
                        error.response.data.errors,
                        { root: true }
                    );
                } else {
                    ctx.dispatch(
                        'setAndDisplayErrors',
                        [ctx.rootState.helper.undefinedErrorMessage],
                        { root: true }
                    );
                }
                reject(error);
            }).finally(() => {
                ctx.commit('setInProcess', false, { root: true });
            })
        })
    },
```

`/login` route:

```php
Route::post("login", [AuthController::class, "login"]);
```

AuthController login() method:

```php
public function login(LoginRequest $request) {
    LoginAction::run($request);
}
```

LoginRequest:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|between:8,255'
        ];
    }
}
```

LoginAction:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;
use Lorisleiva\Actions\Concerns\AsAction;

class LoginAction
{
    use AsAction;

    public function handle($formData)
    {
        $passwordGrantClient = Client::where('password_client', 1)->first();

        $data = [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $passwordGrantClient->id,
            'client_secret' => $passwordGrantClient->secret,
            'username' => $formData->email,
            'password' => $formData->password,
            'scope' => '*'
        ];

        $tokenRequest = Request::create('oauth/token', 'post', $data);
        $tokenResponse = app()->handle($tokenRequest);
        $contentString = $tokenResponse->getContent();
        $tokenContent = json_decode($contentString, true);

        if (!empty($tokenContent['access_token'])) {
            return $tokenResponse;
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => ['Incorrect e-mail or password.']
            ], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! If you need something else to understand my question, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your request. It returns the result, as expected. The error happens in Vuex. And because it's all wrapped in a promise, it's an uncaught error.

To catch the error, I suggest the following syntax:

```
loginUser(ctx, payload) {
  ctx.commit("setInProcess", true, { root: true });
  return axios
    .post("api/login", payload)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      // ...
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // ...
    });
}
```

You'll still get the error, but this time it won't be uncaught, so you'll have more details about it.

Comment: When I said *"there's nothing wrong with your request"* I meant that's not what's throwing the error. In the screenshot you posted, it's quite clear there is `data`, which is an empty string. Trying to read it's `access_token` property is what triggers the error, since it's a string, not an object. Which means that if you change the backend to return an object (e.g: `{ access_token: 'some-token' }`, you don't need to change anything in your app.

Comment: I've just solved my problem, @tao! Thanks for participating!